# sharepoint online root site default page: is this different from any other page?

Tags: sharepoint-online, publishing-page

One thing is happening to the default page of the root site of the tenancy. Minor-Major Versioning is applied with only editors able to see drafts. Check in and out is applied. No approval.

When you are done editing version 3.1, in a normal situation with the same settings all users (with reading permissions) should be able to see version 3.0 (the immediately previous major version). However our readers get access denied. The access denied like this image

https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/TNBlogsFS/prod.evol.blogs.technet.com/CommunityServer.Blogs.Components.WeblogFiles/00/00/00/97/39/metablogapi/2043.image_thumb_4259F093.png

Any other page in the same page library instead behaves as it should, showing users the previous major version.

Is there something not set up right or the default page of the root site collection behaves differently by design?

Comment: If you set a different page to the welcome page what happens? What happens if you navigate directly to the page instead of just the site url?

Comment: you mean if there is a difference between sharepoint.com/pages/home.aspx instead of sharepoint.com and nothing else? I am unable to switch pages cos it is a live environment

Comment: I came to know that there is 'something' custom on the page or in the master page. Do you have an idea what this thing might be? google analytics code would be able to cause something like that?

Comment: It's tough to say what the custom stuff is without getting in and poking around. Try looking at the version history. Try looking at the page layout and its version history. If you can access the logs look in there on the correlation ID.  If not, have an admin fetch them for you. Did the page work before, and suddenly stop working, or has it always done this? Does the page have custom permissions?

Comment: The page is 350+versions, I cannot look at them all. It is the online sharepoint so no logs. The page has got the same permissions as the other pages (who behave correctly) and the rest of the site. Do you think the page might be corrupted or after 350+ versions it might go crazy? does it matter that the whole site collection was copy-pasted from a SP 2010 on premise?